Docker - .NET 8.0 - no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.20348 in the manifest list entries
I try to dockerize a .NET 8.0 app. While the .NET 7.0 example I found works fine, I get issues doing the same with .NET 8.0.
This is what I run and the error I get:
docker build -f Dockerfile -t my-app ..
Sending build context to Docker daemon  18.51MB
Step 1/11 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
8.0: Pulling from dotnet/sdk
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.20348 in the manifest list entries

As I try forcing the platform I get the same problem
docker build --platform windows/amd64 -f Dockerfile -t my-app .. 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  18.51MB
Step 1/11 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
8.0: Pulling from dotnet/sdk
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.20348 in the manifest list entries

Thanks for your help on this one

Multi-platform .NET 8 Docker image tags no longer support Windows containers as announced here.
You can use the 8.0-nanoserver-ltsc2022 tag instead which should support Windows. There's a full tag list for the sdk image here.

should this be only when I build on windows or is it safer to use this on linux too ?

nanoserver is a Windows image, so that only works on Windows. Keep using sdk:8.0 on Linux.
